# How to force a tauri app to open a UAC prompt before running to force administrator?

Tags: rust, uac, administrator, tauri

My tauri app includes it's backend with the frontend code, but the backend code requires administrator to run. I don't want the user to have to right click and run as an administrator every time they want to run the app, so I am wondering how I could make a UAC appear before the app starts to give the app admin.

Comment: This was discussed a few times on tauri's github, for example: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/4201#discussioncomment-3279531